# Jquery validation engine check before to work before onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, phonegap

I’m trying to implement the Jquery validation to work before the onclick function and unfortunately, the onclick function is being called before the validation engine check, making the validation pop up after records have been saved.
How can I enforce validation check before the onclick function?

HTML.html

```
        <script charset="utf-8">
            jQuery(document).ready( function() {
                    jQuery("#Insert").validationEngine();
                });
        </script>

        <form id="Insert"  method="POST" data-ajax="false">
        <label for="name">Name/label>
        <input type="text"  name="FName"  id="FName" class="validate[required]" /><br>

        <input type="button" value="Add"  onClick="Insert()"> 
        </form>
```

JS.js

```
        function Insert(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO tblnames (FName) VALUES ("' +document.getElementById("FName").value+'")', [], success, error);
        }
```

Comment: I think you need to check the documentation for [validation engine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine). Look up the part about **onValidationComplete** And maybe you'll need to replace `input type=button` with `input type=submit`

Comment: Comment not helpful, the implementation is already working. What I need help on is on exactly how question has been asked

Answer (score 2):

How about [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kq3wfs8d/33/)?

The form has `onsubmit="return false;"` so it is not submitted automatically. And when the validation is done, depending on result in `onValidationComplete` function, you can either submit the form or not.

Or, when you need to validate form independently of submitting, use

```
<input type="button" value="Just Button" onclick="jQuery('#Insert').validationEngine('validate')" />
```